# If$ \cos (x-y), \cos x, \cos (x+y)$ are in harmonic progression, find $\cos x \sec \frac y2$

Tags: trigonometry

Since it’s an HP

$$\frac{2}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos (x+y)+\cos (x-y)}{\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)}$$

$$\frac{2}{\cos x}=\frac{2\cos x \cos y}{\cos^2y-\sin^2x}$$

Since, $\cos(a+b)\cos(a-b)=\cos^2b-\sin^2a$

$$\cos^2y-\sin^2x=\cos^2x\cos y$$

What should be the next step?

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-cos-xy-cos-x-and-cos-xy-are-in-hpthen-cos-xsec-y2/

Comment: Add 1 on both sides to get cos^2(x)=(1+cosy) and use double angle formula for RHS.